# Load xml file in Aurelia synchoniously

Tags: aurelia

I have a configuration class that needs to load an xml file on starting my aurelia application. Now my problem is, that I have no Idea how to load that file so that I have the information present when I need them.

In my current implementation I'm using the aurelia-fetch-client for reading the information, but that leads to the point that the information are not present in time :/

Can somebody give me a hint how to implement that in a good way?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem? Why is the "information not present in time"? When do you need the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was discussed in detail in the [Aurelia Discourse board](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/loading-a-xml-file-once/1456/8) with the result that it's all about delaying `aurelia.start()` as long as you haven't loaded and processed the xml file.